# Problems updating to PHP 5.3 on CENTOS 5.8

Tags: php, installation, centos

I'm trying to update PHP on Centos 5.8 via a program called "PuTTY", I followed this tutorial: http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php53/ and that didn't work, so I tried this one: http://www.andresmontalban.com/update-centos-5-php-5-1-to-php-5-3/ and a few others, and every one I've tried I get the same errors "No package php available" or when I try add the repositorys I get "transfer failed - Unknown or unexpected error" does anyone know what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: maybe serverfault might have a better explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from CentOS 5.6, PHP 5.3 is available in packages starts with php53. You can do a

```
yum search php53
```

to get the list of packages. However, you need to uninstall ALL PHP 5.1.6 packages (i.e. packages starts with 'php') before yum install the php53 packages. Furthermore, you need to install PEAR on your own (download go-pear.phar from pear.php.net and execute it using the php  cli).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did the search and it returned no matches found